# How to iterate over multiple related lists until specified number times in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I want to iterate to Nth times my list. This is my example code.

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
b = [i - 1 for i in a]
print(b)
c = [i * 10 for i in b]
print(c)
d = [i / 3 for i in c]
print(d)
a = [m/n for m,n in zip(d,a)]
print(a)
b=[i - 1 for i in a]
print(b)
c = [i * 10 for i in b]
print(c)
d = [i / 3 for i in c]
print(d)
a = [m/n for m,n in zip(d,a)]
print(a)
```

For example, I want to do iteration 10 times over all the lists. But I don't want to write those same codes 10 times. Is there efficient way to get my desired results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write a function for the iteration logics and pass the list `a` as argument to it..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't actually need the intermediate lists, you can combine all the maths ops into one:

```
def func(a, n):
   for _ in range(n):
      a = [(i-1)*10/(3*i) for i in a]
   return a
```

Comment: I run your code. It doesn't print anything. It happens exit code 0.

Comment: a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
n = 10
for k in range(n):
    a = [(i - 1) * 10 / (3 * i) for i in a]
    print(a) This works. I don't know what is the different.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use something like this

```
def lists_iteration(a,n):
    for k in range(n):
        b = [i - 1 for i in a]
        print(b)
        c = [i * 10 for i in b]
        print(c)
        d = [i / 3 for i in c]
        print(d)
        a = [m/n for m,n in zip(d,a)]
        print(a)
```

or just for loop from this function.

Comment: I run your code. It doesn't print anything. It happens exit code 0.

Comment: It's a function which accept a list as `a` and number of iterations as `n`. It works on my Python 3.6.2. You should call function to see your intermediate lists.
I've fixed function: `for k in range(n):`

Comment: `a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
n = 8
for k in range(n+1):
        b = [i - 1 for i in a]

        c = [i * 10 for i in b]

        d = [i / 3 for i in c]

        a = [m/n for m,n in zip(d,a)]
        print(a)`                                                                                       When I run above code. It woks. But with function it doesn't. Can u explain me theory behind it.Thanks.

Comment: Actually I don't know, why it doesn't work for you... Are you trying

`a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
n = 8

lists_iteration(a, n)`

after defying function?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> x = [(i-1,(i-1)*10,((i-1)*10)/3) for i in a]
>>> print x 
[(1, 10, 3), (3, 30, 10), (5, 50, 16), (7, 70, 23), (9, 90, 30)] 
>>>
>>> b = [i[0] for i in x ]
>>> print b
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> c = [i[1] for i in x]
>>> print c
[10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
>>> d = [i[2] for i in x]
>>> print d 
[3, 10, 16, 23, 30]
```